# is it possible to execute javascript code in the .net framework?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

i want to be able to execute JavaScript on the server side which is running the .net environment.
so how is it possible to do so?
mainly i need text processing functions, i will input a string and get a string returned from JavaScript code.
no window interaction is needed.

Comment: .Net is pretty good for text processing. Is there something specific you need that only JavaScript can provide?

Comment: I'd second @MarceloCantos' comment. What's the advantage of going outside of .Net for text processing?

Comment: This seems like a bizarre thing to want to do. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need to test JavaScript code that it performs correctly. that is in an automatic way.

Comment: There are a host of javascript unit testing frameworks out there.

Comment: Jasmine, Mocha, CucumberJs to name a few

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are several JS engines which you can use. [Jurassic](https://github.com/paulbartrum/jurassic), [Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) and [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS) are .NET-based, but you can also interface to others such as the V8 from the Chrome browser or the ActiveScript from IE.

**EDIT:** Five years later the JS engines native to .NET are somewhat lagging behind (none supports ES6 yet, and IronJS seems abandoned), but we now also have the open-source [ChakraCore](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore) which is not very hard to integrate and use in .NET with one of the readily available wrappers.

Also, the [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher) allows using almost any of the existing JS engines from within .NET code through a common interface, so that switching engines does not need changing code.

Comment: any links on how to interact with chrome or ie javascript engines?

Comment: it looks like Jint is the best option :)

Comment: Cool of you to come back and update this years later. Going to check out ChakraCore now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can write a [JScript.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) file and compile it into an assembly with [`jsc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7435xtz6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), then just use that assembly like any other.

Example:

```
package Your.Desired.Package.Name {
    Class SomeClassName {
        public static function doSomething(foo) }
            var bar;

            // Fairly normal JavaScript code here

            if (foo.match(/sometest/)) {
                // Do something
            }
            else {
                // Do something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other than the `package` and `class` structures, the code in JScript.Net is essentially JavaScript. You even have `eval` if you want to be evil. :-)

You then compile that into an assembly like this:

```
jsc /target:library TheFileName.js
```

...and it produces and assembly in `TheFileName.dll`.